# Convert Apache "Is Not" rule to Nginx

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, apache2

I have an Apache rewrite rule that works to prevent author enumeration on a Wordpress site. However, in order to maintain proper functionality in the Wordpress admin, this rule does not apply to any requests with `/wp-admin` in the URI.

```
# apache

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} author=\d [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=403]
```

**What is an appropriate Nginx equivalent?**

Some things I know:

1. Nginx considers Apache's "is not" rule to be "upside down logic" and as such, doesn't support a similar concept.
2. Nginx doesn't support nested `if` statements or multiple conditions `if (THIS && THAT) {}`
3. Nginx evaluates `if` statements on every request, which is not ideal for performance.
4. Nginx considers `if` statements to be "evil" in the context of locations, and furthers notes that these if statements may behave unexpectedly. As such, recommends avoiding them.

This doesn't leave me with very many options. I've managed to come up with the following config, though I'd prefer something that doesn't introduce performance concerns and/or jeopardizes stability.

```
# nginx

location / {
    set $MATCH "";
    if ($uri !~* "^/wp-admin") { set $MATCH A; }
    if ($args ~ "^author=\d") { set $MATCH "${MATCH}B"; }
    if ($MATCH = AB) { return 403; }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

**How can this be done better?**

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use two `location` blocks:

```
location / {
    if ($arg_author ~ ^\d) { return 403; }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location /wp-admin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Used `if` block is [completely safe](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/):

> The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are:
>
> ```
> return ...;
> rewrite ... last;
> ```